# Youtube Video PLaylist name

Tags: youtube-data-api

How do I show playlist name on a page for a specific youtube video?
using youtube data api I can fetch all data of a video and can show on my wordpress page. But
Couldn't show playlist/category name on page.
please help with code

Comment: I can't get precisely what you are really interested in since a video can be in multiple playlists. Do you want not just embed the video but a whole playlist on your website ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If A video is in multiply playlists, I want to show all the playlist as category name

Comment: I don't get what you mean by category name but AFAIK you can't get all playlists containing a video only from this video id. The *only solution* would be to get access to all playlists on YouTube but discovering all of them is a very complicated problem in itself